# Andengine with Samsung spen sdk

Tags: android, andengine, galaxy, samsung-mobile-sdk

Im developping a game using andengine which draws on a opengl renderSurfaceView. I want to add SPen functions to the game.So my approach was to use mSPenEventLibrary and pass renderSurfaceView as a parameter to its onTouchListner.

mSPenEventLibrary.setSPenTouchListener(mRenderSurfaceView, new SPenTouchListener() ..

Now the problem is motion event invokes the spenEventLibrary touchlistner but not the andengines onTouchListners.I want to invoke them both. How can I solve this problem

Is there another way to use andengine with the spen sdk?

Thank you!

Comment: Correct link to the answer concerning AndEngine with the S Pen SDK: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SPenSDK&messageId=173798